# use str_replace to remove after @

Tags: php, str-replace

How can I use the str_replace() without using an array of words for turning:

```
some@mail.com
```

into

```
some
```

So, everything after the '@' sign includes @ as well.
How can I do that?
As an example, i will type 'adminofsite@xxxwwweeerandomstuff.com'
and the output will be: 'adminofsite'.

Comment: Reading the documentation would be a good place to start.  [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).  Other options include splitting into an array and taking the first item in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use strstr

```
$email="john@doe.com"
$user = strstr($email, '@', true);
echo $user;
```

Comment: This is not a full answer, you should provide appropriate text explaining the issue and why this works

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = "some@mail.com"
$str = substr($str,0,strpos($str,"@"))
```

Comment: This is not a full answer, you should provide appropriate text explaining the issue and why this works

Answer (score 0):

```
function stripEmailDomain($string){
    return substr($string, 0, strpos($string, '@'));
}
```

Comment: This is not a full answer, you should provide appropriate text explaining the issue and why this works.

Comment: That is reasonable. It’s unfortunate you didn’t post this on the other similar answer

Comment: That one didn't show up for me on the low quality answers queue.

Answer (score 0):

I exploded and then rebuilt the string. This will work if you are positive the string will always be an email address. Its a work around but seems flexible if you want to modify it for a specific purpose.

```
<?php
$explo0= explode('@',"some@mail.com");

for($i=0;$i<count($explo0);$i++){

        $exploresult0.=$explo0[$i+1];   
}
echo "@".$exploresult0;
```

?>